# How to use Filters in CgridView in yii to achieve Sorting and Searching

Tags: yii

I have created a array and put it in the CActiveDataProvider and rendering to the CGridView. I have my own extra column in the GridView. I am unable to sort the extra added column. If i use filters in CGridview it shows error as the extra column is not defined. Should i use CArrayDataProvider or CActiveDataProvider. Please anyone help me out. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The type of data provider has non (or not important) influence on CGridView behaviour. You decide with type to use, when you know what kind of data you'll feed it with?

If you are using ActiveRecord to retrieve data from database, then you use CActiveDataProvider. If you want to run a single SQL query, then you use CSqlDataProvider. And finally, if you have dataset in form of array (extracted from database or not), you'll use CArrayDataProvider.

Question on, why your extra added column isn't used in sorting and question, which data provider use are kind of two different questions.

Can you provide more details? What kind of data you put into your extra column? What is source of this data? Do you included this column among other columns to be sorted or searched?